# Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{thebibliography}

Tags: bibtex

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,cspaper,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%
%%%%%%
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\SetEndCharOfAlgoLine{} % don't print semicolon in algo
\makeatother
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\begin{document}





%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What happens when you add `\nocite{*}`?

Comment: Do you have any news for us?